# contextAPI return state with undefined

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-context, react-state

I'm using contextAPI with useState, and the initial value is an Object with Themes.

but when i give console.log this return undefined

```
export interface ITheme {
  themeMode: DefaultTheme
  setThemeMode: Dispatch<SetStateAction<DefaultTheme>>
}
interface IThemeProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode
}

const initialValues: ITheme = {
  themeMode: themesSchema.light,
  setThemeMode: () => null
}

export const ToggleThemeContext = createContext<ITheme>({} as ITheme)

export function ToggleThemeContextProvider({ children }: IThemeProviderProps) {
  const deviceTheme = useColorScheme()
  const firstThemeChoice = themesSchema[deviceTheme ? deviceTheme : 'light']
  
  const [themeMode, setThemeMode] = useState<DefaultTheme>(firstThemeChoice)
 
  const value = {
    themeMode, 
    setThemeMode
  }

  return (
    <ToggleThemeContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </ToggleThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

and i created a custom hook for this

```
export function useToggleTheme(): ITheme {
  const context = useContext(ToggleThemeContext)
  //Using this hook you always need to pass in the setThemeMode(example)
  //being example -----> const example = colorScheme['light' | 'dark']
  return context
}
```

I used provider in App.

when i do this, in my app because i need to use this the ThemeProvider from styled-components

```js
const { themeMode } = useToggleTheme()
console.log(themeMode) //Undefined
```

My App

```
export default function App() {
 
  const { themeMode } = useToggleTheme()
  return (
    <HeaderContextProvider>
      <ToggleThemeContextProvider> 
        <ThemeProvider theme={themeMode}>
          <SafeAreaProvider>
            {fontsLoaded ? <Routes /> : <Loading />}
            <StatusBar style="auto" backgroundColor="transparent" translucent />
          </SafeAreaProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </ToggleThemeContextProvider>
    </HeaderContextProvider>
  )
}
```

I tried using InitialValues in createContext, but when i use the setThemeMode, that doesnt work. I have other context just using boolean, that returns undefined too. but when i use setXXX that update the state

Comment: Don't put screenshots of code, please copy and paste instead.

Comment: How do you apply the provider, can you post the code as well?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this...

We cant use values from Provider inside the App.tsx
If you want to do this you need to use the Cosumer...

On this case i created a context About theme colors... and the theme was to ThemeProvider from styled components...

So, using Context.Consumer Everything works good